# How do I display the total percentage and count together as a stacked bar chart without formatting all data to percentage values?

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-chart

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306339/it-is-possible-to-sort-by-valid-percentage-in-my-data) (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327211/is-it-possible-to-display-percentage-and-count-together)) recently, and even though both have solutions, I am left with a new dilemma because each solution only works on an independent level (i.e. one solution won't work if the other solution is in place).

The problem is this: In Tableau, I discovered that by opting to display the data as a percentage of the total row value `Analysis > Percentage of > Row`, it resulted in the `count` value also being displayed as a number between 0 and 1 (i.e. percentage format, because of the aforementioned percentage-only setting).

Is there a way to achieve a 100.00% stacked bar which shows both percentage AND count, and which also isn't formatted to display all data as a percentage of the row total?

The screenshot shows what happens when both solutions are in place.  Original screenshots are available within the body of each of the previous questions.

**Note:** I feel that the right way to go about it might be to normalise my data (bringing all values to a scale between 0 and 1), but being new to Tableau, I am not sure how this is achieved.  If this is correct, I would appreciate a walkthrough.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the second SUM({Number of Records]) pill on the Label shelf, and clear the table calc. Edit your label if needed

Comment: Great, I used this advice and adjusted my label values, and it is now working - thank you!